# iOS: how to create buttons inside a rectangle?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I do not have much experience on this but I want to position two UIButtons inside a rectangle as in the image below. So what is the best way to do that? I do not want to draw an image of rectangle from Photoshop and import into xCode. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drag a UIView onto your Storyboard 
and then drag your buttons onto that, so they are subviews.
The storyboard would look like:

```
view controller
  -view (main)
      -view (your new subview)
           -button1
           -button2
```

Then you can set the background etc on the subview to visually define the rectangle

Comment: I am not using storyboard, is it the same as without using storyboard?

Comment: I don't understand.  But
you could do it programmatically:

     `UIView* theRectangle = [UIView initWithFrame(theRectangleFrame)];
     UIButton button1 = [UIButton ...etc

     UIButton button2 = [UIButton ...etc

       [theRectangle addSubview:button1];
        [theRectangle addSubview:button2];
      [mainView addSubview:theRectangle];`
`